# Is it possible to put assembly instructions into CUDA code?

Tags: c, assembly, cuda, inline-assembly, ptx

I want to use assembly code in CUDA C code
in order to reduce expensive executions
as we do using **asm** in c programming.

Is it possible?

Comment: Related on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/668019/how-do-device-driver-instructions-program-the-gpu For Intel's Xeon Phi it looks possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create or manipulate GPU assembler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660974/how-to-create-or-manipulate-gpu-assembler)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't, there is nothing like the asm constructs from C/C++. What you can do is tweak the generated PTX assembly and then use it with CUDA.

See [this](http://wili.cc/blog/ptx.html) for an example.

But for GPUs, assembly optimizations are NOT necessary, you should do other optimizations first, such as memory coalescency and occupancy. See the [CUDA Best Practices guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Best_Practices_Guide.pdf) for more information.

Comment: Second that!  In my experience, CUDA programs are almost always memory bound, not compute bound.

Comment: thanks above both. I just wanted to reduce the number of division and modulo operations, but now I will focus on the memory issue.

Comment: Note, if you're compiling against the newest architecture (using the flag -arch sm_20), the newest API is now fully?? compliant with IEEE floating point specifications for division and square root.  If you've got a bunch of divisions and you're also using -arch sm_20, then you might consider switching back to the "less" compliant version for a performance gain using the flag:  __-prec-div=false__   http://forums.nvidia.com/lofiversion/index.php?t170749.html

Comment: Suggest unaccepting this answer and accepting njuffa's, since time has made this answer less useful thanks to new features.

Answer (score 21):

Since CUDA 4.0, inline PTX is supported by the CUDA toolchain. There is a document in the toolkit that describes it: Using_Inline_PTX_Assembly_In_CUDA.pdf

Below is some code demonstrating use of inline PTX in CUDA 4.0. Note that this code should not be used as a replacement for CUDA's built-in __clz() function, I merely wrote it to explore aspects of the new inline PTX capability.

```
__device__ __forceinline__ int my_clz (unsigned int x)
{
    int res;

    asm ("{\n"
         "        .reg .pred iszero, gezero;\n"
         "        .reg .u32 t1, t2;\n"
         "        mov.b32         t1, %1;\n"
         "        shr.u32         %0, t1, 16;\n"
         "        setp.eq.b32     iszero, %0, 0;\n"
         "        mov.b32         %0, 0;\n"
         "@iszero shl.b32         t1, t1, 16;\n"
         "@iszero or.b32          %0, %0, 16;\n"
         "        and.b32         t2, t1, 0xff000000;\n"
         "        setp.eq.b32     iszero, t2, 0;\n"
         "@iszero shl.b32         t1, t1, 8;\n"
         "@iszero or.b32          %0, %0, 8;\n"
         "        and.b32         t2, t1, 0xf0000000;\n"
         "        setp.eq.b32     iszero, t2, 0;\n"
         "@iszero shl.b32         t1, t1, 4;\n"
         "@iszero or.b32          %0, %0, 4;\n"
         "        and.b32         t2, t1, 0xc0000000;\n"
         "        setp.eq.b32     iszero, t2, 0;\n"
         "@iszero shl.b32         t1, t1, 2;\n"
         "@iszero or.b32          %0, %0, 2;\n"
         "        setp.ge.s32     gezero, t1, 0;\n"
         "        setp.eq.b32     iszero, t1, 0;\n"
         "@gezero or.b32          %0, %0, 1;\n"
         "@iszero add.u32         %0, %0, 1;\n\t"
         "}"
         : "=r"(res)
         : "r"(x));
    return res;
}
```