# How can I compile offline opencl kernel files for adreno GPU？

Tags: opencl, qualcomm

I can not compile runtime for some security reason.
I can not compile runtime for some security reason.

I tried adreno offline compiler, but I could not fine the output file.
I tried adreno offline compiler, but I could not fine the output file.

Comment: I don't know about the specifics of adreno, but OpenCL allows you to build your program from source, or build from binary (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23601058/how-to-create-do-offline-compilation-in-opencl-and-create-its-binary), which is a semi-precompiled intermediate representation of your kernel code. An OpenCL program will always have to at least build from binary at runtime.

Comment: yes but I think the binary also should be compiled runtime from program on my adreno device