# How to Detect L0,L1,L2 Cache Possible overflow just by looking at the kernel Code?

Tags: caching, optimization, memory, memory-management, opencl

I have a [RX 570](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/radeon-rx-570.c2939), These are the information i received from clGetDeviceInfo

```
MaxComputeUnitPerGPU: 32

MaxWorkGroupSize: 256

MaxWorkItemSize: 256

MaxGlobalMemoryOfDevice: 4294967296

MaxPrivateMemoryBytesPerWorkGroup: 16384

MaxLocalMemoryBytesPerWorkGroup: 32768
```

If I have 256 Work Groups and 256 Work Items per Work Group It would mean that

```
64 Bytes Of Private(l1?) Memory per work Item(16384/256)
32768 Bytes Of Local(l2) Memory per work Group
```

And if I use 17 ***floats*** would it overflow to L2?

*or*

If I use 15 ***float***, and 2 ***private float*** would it overflow to L2?

also is ***float*** the same as ***private float***? Answer: Same by default, By @doqtor

*or*

If I use 16 ***float*** and use functions like ***pow, sqrt and clamp*** would registry(l1?) overflow occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables without address specifier are by default private. By [OpenCL docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/private.html):

> Variables inside a __kernel function not declared with an address
> space qualifier, all variables inside non-kernel functions, and all
> function arguments are in the __private or private address space.
> Variables declared as pointers are considered to point to the
> __private address space if an address space qualifier is not specified.

Private variables are stored in registers on GPU. If the kernel uses more registers than available, some variables are stored instead in global memory (register spilling).

Comment: Thanks for the info about private!
But is Detecting Registry spillage simple as counting the number of floats declared?

Comment: I think you can expect that but I would consult CodeXL for example.

Comment: Thanks! Is I will try CodeXL, Also does CodeXL give information about Registry usage of functions(inline) in kernel? like pow,sqrt and clamp for example

Comment: I don't know, I haven't been using it for years.

Comment: well thanks for the other answers! I will now wait for function's registry usage answer...

Comment: I haven't noticed that you added one more question. Functions like `pow` shouldn't increase register usage as they are internal part of the language.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering! i have marked your answer as the Answer!

Answer (score 1):

To add to doqtor's answer, you can detect register spilling by doing roofline analysis if you are in the bandwidth limit. You can count the number of FLOPs and memory transfers from the program binaries (`string binaries = program.getInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES>()[0]);`). If you are very close to the bandwidth limit, then there is no spilling. If you increase the number of private variables from this point, for example with a matrix multiplication in private memory, and performance significantly drops, then you have a register spill: `private` variables are suddenly read from `global` memory and since you already were in the bandwidth limit, the additional global memory access leads to slowdown.

Comment: Once again thanks for helping me on this subject too!
but can you please tell me more about *getInfo* in terms of *clGetProgramInfo* I don't know how to get the "binary" when i use *clGetProgramInfo* as for *getinfo* i don't have code for this

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7338930/9178992 Alternatively, you can also count FLOPs and memory access directly in the OpenCL C code. FLOPs don't not have to be exact, the order of magnitude for the arithmetic intensity is enough.

Comment: The said Code in the link,
Has Mistmatched parameters... and i do not know match the parameters correctly...
This linke for example, 
`errcode = clGetProgramInfo(program, CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES, binary_sizes, number_of_binaries * sizeof(int), &number_of_binaries);`