# "don't know what to do with' nvcc fatal error

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, nvcc

I use the command lines in Ubuntu's terminal.

And I am trying to compile the three files presented in CUDA_Compiler_Driver_NVCC.pdf

When I do use the command line given by the documentation on these 3 files, I do get the following errors:

nvcc fatal : don't know what to do with'-dc'

If I erase -dc in the command line, I do get the following error too: 
nvcc fatal : don't know what to do with'-arch=sm=20'

Do anyone know how I could fix this issue ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Gibo

Below, you will find the command line I entered in the terminal, and the files.

Command line used: 
nvcc –arch=sm_20 –dc a.cu b.cu
nvcc –arch=sm_20 a.o b.o

Files code (just a copy paste of the documentation): 
(it seems the code police changes when pasted, sorry for this small issue)

```
******* b.h ***********
#define N 8

extern __device__ int g[N];
extern __device__ void bar(void);

******* b.cu***********
#include "b.h"
__device__ int g[N];
__device__ void bar (void)
{
g[threadIdx.x]++;
}

******* a.cu ***********
#include <stdio.h>

#include "b.h"

__global__ void foo (void) {
__shared__ int a[N];
a[threadIdx.x] = threadIdx.x;
__syncthreads();
g[threadIdx.x] = a[blockDim.x - threadIdx.x - 1];
}

bar();

int main (void) {
unsigned int i;
int *dg, hg[N];

int sum = 0;

foo<<<1, N>>>();

if(cudaGetSymbolAddress((void**)&dg, g)){
printf("couldn't get the symbol addr\n");
return 1;
}

if(cudaMemcpy(hg, dg, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)){
printf("couldn't memcpy\n");
return 1;
}

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
sum += hg[i];
}

if (sum == 36) {
printf("PASSED\n");
} else {
printf("FAILED (%d)\n", sum);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you supply link to mentioned PDF? I checked with [nvcc manpage](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/45/idpl/12463013/numer/1/nazwa/nvcc) and it has no flags like `-dc` or `--arch`. Also, I'd assume that `--arch` specifies target hardware architecture, so I can't get it why it is given twice.

Comment: Yes Filip here it is p46-47 : http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CUDA_Compiler_Driver_NVCC.pdf

Comment: Read chapter 6 (page 29 of this pdf) for explanation of `-arch` flag. Still searching for any mention of `-dc`

Comment: the -arch is used to specify the type of architecture I use. I tried them all sm_21 sm_13 etc. it seems the error does not come from this. I wonder whether it is from configuration purposes or something. I might be wrong since I am new to Ubuntu

Comment: But you didn't specify code. I'm still at "search topics" stage, not "read those topics", but as far as I've seen, you always use `-arch` with `-code`, and its values may be the same. Also, read what other options you should use for those to be available (maybe they are used only on some special compilation phase?).

Comment: Als `-dc` is explained in 7.3, page 38. Do you really need both those options, or are you trying to start with CUDA and compile ANY program at all?

Comment: Well, after I read your answer, I wonder if these commands are useful. Because I do use a GeforceGTX620 and not one of Tesla type or something. It might effectively be related. The point is I am trying to compile the CUDA code example, and then I will compile new code

Comment: And I am no CUDA expert, I just thought that those options look like overkill when trying to run code from PDF ;) Try without them, if you're gonna have a problem then - edit this post, I'm gonna watch it, and help you if I can. Btw: read the whole PDF, and do some notes while reading, I think it will be easier then ;)

Comment: yes I used it without and I get the following post: ./a.cu(11): Error: External calls are not supported (found non-inlined call to _Z3barv)   So in a sense, it seems it is a new type of error.

Comment: Good thing I said I'm no expert :D

Comment: But if it does not detect the content of the bar() function defined in the b.cu file, then there is something wrong with the compilation. Don't you think the -arch commands help ? here is a link of dc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994005/cuda-external-calls-not-supported

Comment: With the -dc command, it might be linked to the CUDA version. I had issues seting up the 5.5 version, so I set  up the 4.2, but it seems the -dc declaration was improved since the 5.0 version, I still need to check it, but it might be a clue

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using the right version of nvcc. I had a problem like that and it was because I was using NVCC 5.5 instead of 6.0.

Also make sure the dashes have the right symbol: use - (0x2D) and not – (0xD0).

Comment: It did the job for me! I copied paste something from the internet and some how the - symbols got mixed!