# How can I see the assembly code generated in a Visual Studio Cuda Project?

Tags: c++, assembly, cuda

To check the assembly code in a normal project I simply go change the

*Property in Project Properties->ConfigurationProperties->C/C++->Output Files->Assembler Output* to **Assembly-Only Listing (/FA)**

But in CUDA projects I can't find this option available:
[image]

So how can I have access to the assembly generated code? I want to the see the release code so I can't use the debugger.

Comment: This answer provides some background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353136/is-there-an-assembly-language-for-cuda. The assembler is not x86 (it's specific to the GPU processor) so CUDA tends to be directly compiled to the object code. As far as Debugging goes, Nvidia has their own debugger plugin for VS: https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition

Answer (score 2):

Locate the generated executable, say `StackOverflow.com`, go to that directory and type

```
cuobjdump StackOverflow.com --dump-sass
```

This will show the disassembly of all the compiled kernels. The assembly primitives are reported in the CUDA Binary Utilities guide.